# Lenovo Vibe K5 is not turning on anymore

Tags: cyanogenmod, unbricking, lenovo

I have rooted Lenovo Vibe K5 and I had installed CM 13 (Marshmallow). It was working well, but because of some need, I had to install CM 12.1 (Lollipop) and I tried installing through TWRP recovery CM 12.1. I wiped Dalvik, Cache, and System and installed CM 12.1 successfully and was asked to reboot the system and I clicked on reboot. After that, it didn't turn on, not even in recovery mode by pressing and holding the Volume + and Power buttons.

Then I tried to flash it again with PC but it's not showing in CMD as well. It shows the error "Device not found" in CMD and in Windows notification, it shows "USB Device not recognized".

Answer (score 0):

In this state, flashing the stock firmware still the solution. You need drivers for the PC to detect the phone.

- Click [here](https://gsmdrivers.blogspot.com/2016/08/lenovo-vibe-k5-a6020a40-usb-flashing-driver-or-flash-tool.html?m=1) to get the USB drivers and the flash tool.
- Click [here](http://techxat.com/restore-lenovo-vibe-k5-stock-android-5-1-lollipop-firmware/) to get the flash file (firmware).

*Alternative download links:*

- *[**Firmware**](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4fnd/Dz2wgQs9d)*
- [**Flash tool**](https://gsmdrivers.blogspot.in/2016/08/lenovo-vibe-k5-a6020a40-usb-flashing-driver-or-flash-tool.html)
- [**Drivers**](https://gsmdrivers.blogspot.in/2016/08/lenovo-vibe-k5-a6020a40-usb-flashing-driver-or-flash-tool.html)

**FLASHING STEPS:**

- First download firmware, flash tool and/or drivers from above links.
- Extract zipped files to desktop or anywhere you'd like (You'll need winrar or 7zip software to Extract).
- Open Driver folder and choose  Qualcomm_USB_Driver_Setup.exe file and wait until finish installation.
- Open QPST.WIN.2.7_Installer-00430.1 folder and chose setup.exe file, open and install it.
- Now open QFIL from the "C:\Program Files\Qualcomm\QPST\bin" path, Select Programmer option and click on *Browse button* and Select `prog_emmc_firehose_8929.mbn` from SW Folder file.
- Click on Load XML button and choose
  `rawprogram0.xml` file and then choose  `patch0.xml` file from the SW Folder folder.
- Press and hold **Volume Up + Volume Down** and insert USB cable and wait until driver install are installed.
- Click on Download button and wait until flashing process finishes.

Oh, and you may need a video tutorial to make it easier, find it here: 
[**Flashing process**](https://youtu.be/sM2-hw8pIM8)

Comment: Thanks @esQmo, i installed the driver but its still not detecting my phone in ADB mode, not even in windows , it shows USB Device not recognized :( but yeah it shows the Notification LED indicator light.

Comment: You can't connect in ADB mode since your phone is off. You have to flash it in this state. Open the flash tool, load the firmware and click on the flashing button then connect your switched off phone with the USB cable to the computer, the flashing process should start.

Comment: If it's showing "Device not recognized" it is probably the cable is damaged, or the USB connector could be damaged too, or has some dirt

Comment: in QFIL there's two Build type, Flat and meta build , which one to choose? by default its clicked on meta build, and it does not let me browse programmer path and i'm also unable to find "rog_emmc_firehose_8929.mbn" this file.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHUX3FVQ1pSdTNXbFU

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHURWRSeEw3eUJaRDA                       can i get you on google plus  or whatsapp ?

Comment: Leave it in flat build and in "PROGRAMMER PATH" field, click Browse and go to the folder named Images and select the one file it displays (something like prog_emmc....mbn).

Comment: i am doing exactly the way you told, i have installed both lenovo and Qualcomm usb drivers , i am pressing Volume up + Down keys, but  its still not showing my phone, No Port Available. Whenever i plug the phone in pc it shows device not recognized then littile later it installs this . check the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHURWRSeEw3eUJaRDA

Comment: I don't get you, what is been installed? I see nothing on the screenshot.

Comment: I also told you that of the PC still showing device not received, your cable is probably damaged or the phone USB connector.

Comment: We can connect on WhatsApp or Twitter, or Google+ .

Comment: i found a little progress. check the link                               https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHUVVFvUjRGUFEyN0E                                                                  and found this new problem as well Swtich to EDL Fail .

Comment: Is the phone detected in Fastboot mode? if so, run `fastboot oem reboot-edl`

Comment: error : device is not found in CMD     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHUOUViVzNnajJ2b2s

Comment: The phone is not in fastboot mode. Put it in fastboot mode first then tape the comand